# Mysql query, contains a string then 3 numbers in email

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have a mysql database with a table that contains an email address entered by website users.

How would I select all records where the email field contains any number of characters, then 3 numbers and @yahoo.com

i.e. testemail639@yahoo.com

Comment: You would use MySQL's [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html).

Answer (score 2):

A simple way would be to use `REGEXP` in your SELECT statements.

```
SELECT * FROM records WHERE email REGEXP '^\w+\d{3}\@.*$'
```

The above statement is untested, but should lead you down a better road.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE email REGEXP '[0-9]{3}@yahoo\.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM records WHERE email REGEXP '^\w+([\.-]?\w+)?([0-9]{3})@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$'
```

`^\w+([\.-]?\w+)?([0-9]{3})@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$` strictly checks *string* followed by *3 numbers pattern* in the **email** containing no spaces